# mass assignment .update not calling dependent: :destroy on children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

As the title suggests I have a model with a has_many association. This also has it's own has_many association but I'll get onto that later.

```rb
class List < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items, dependent: :destroy
end
```

```rb
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :list
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
end
```

```
current_ids = [2, 4, 5]

list.update(item_ids: [2,4]) #should destroy item with id: 5 and subsequent messages.
```

on the parent, I call .update and will remove an id from the array of id's associated with this model. This should in turn destroy the child and cascade through to destroying it's own has_many messages associations. But I'm getting a foreign key constraint error suggesting that I am orphaning the last has_many association.

When testing the dependent: :destroy method, it appears it's not being run at all on either the Items or the Messages.

Am I missing something?

Expected behaviour. update list with new item id's, destroy removed items and subsequent messages

Comment: Why would deleting a join record (`item_lists`) also delete the association (`item`)? The link between an `item_lists` and an `items` is actually a `belongs_to`, not a `has_many`. Perhaps it would help if you clarified exactly what you expect to be destroyed, what the foreign key constraint is, and what the orphaned record is.

Comment: edited for clarity. apologies. writing too quick, forgot the belongs_to

Comment: @TomLord - i don't have an item_lists join in this situation. apologies for missing the belongs_to association here. The removal of the item_id should only destroy the item and the messages for that item. currently the error I am getting is that the item id is still being referenced on the table 'messages'